# Restaurar archivos borrados por hard reset

Tags: git

Usé el comando `git reset --hard` y quiero saber si hay alguna forma de recuperar los archivos que fueron eliminados.

No puedo volver a un commit anterior porque no realicé ninguno.

Aún no cierro el terminal creo que esos archivos están alojados aún en algún lugar pero no sé cómo restablecerlos.

Comment: Si lo que quieres recuperar son archivos no trackeados por git, es decir archivos que no están incluidos en ningún commit, no hay modo (mediante git) de recuperarlos.

Comment: Yo logré recuperarlos con recuva

Comment: Hay un comando llamado `git reflog`. Ando muy flojo para investigar y crear una respuesta, así que les dejo el tema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard

Answer (score 1):

Si el archivo a recuperar era trackeado por GIT entonces simplemente usa:

```
git checkout /ruta_del_archivo/nombre_del_archivo_eliminado
```

Y debería regresar a la vida tu archivo accidentalmente eliminado.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy leyendo sobre escenarios para recuperar archivos con git, y de lo que encontré se puede dividir en las siguientes secciones:

1. Archivos que no fueron puestos en stage (no hubo un `git add` sobre esos archivos)
2. Archivos que fueron puestos en stage pero no se les hizo un commit (solo `git add`, pero no `git commit`)
3. Archivos que fueron agregados en un commit

### 1) Ni en el stage ni en un commit

Suponiendo que perdiste estos archivos, esto ya no es tema de *git*, sino de otras herramientas.

Algunas estrategias que he visto son:

- Revisar la caché o local storage del editor o IDE usado (sublime, intellij, vim, emacs, atom, etc)
- Utilzar herramientas para recuperar archivos según el sistema operativo, un ejemplo es `debugfs`

### 2) En el stage pero no en un commit

Digamos que tenemos la siguiente estructura de archivos no vacíos:

```
uno    <- En un commit
dos    <- En un commit
tres   <- En stage
cuatro <- En stage
```

En el *stage* significa que para "tres" y "cuatro" solo hicimos alguna de las dos opciones:

```sh
git add .
# o:
git tres cuatro
```

Pero no hicimos *commit*. Y en lugar de eso nos equivocamos e hicimos un `git reset --hard`, lo cual nos borró lo que estaba en stage, es decir, los archivos "tres" y "cuatro".

Aquí podemos utilizar el comando `git fsck --lost-found`, que recuperará el contenido de los archivos, pero no su nombre original, sino con algún hash.

El contenido se encontrará en algún lugar dentro de nuestra carpeta `.git/lost+found`:

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 19c70a3e67953361e0cb365291fee552a4872e6c
dangling blob 5c1b14949828006ed75a3e8858957f86a2f7e2eb
$ cat .git/lost-found/other/*
───────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: .git/lost-found/other/19c70a3e67953361e0cb365291fee552a4872e6c
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ adios
───────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
───────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: .git/lost-found/other/5c1b14949828006ed75a3e8858957f86a2f7e2eb
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ hola
───────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Y ahí puedes ver tus archivos que estaban en stage pero no se les hizo commit.

### 3) En un commit

Aquí puede ser el caso que tengamos una grafica de *git* como esta:

```
* a66c2c9 (HEAD -> master) add:archivos cinco y seis
* 00654ea add:archivos tres y cuatro
* 3005716 add:archivos uno y dos
```

Que describa la creación de nuestros archivos:

```
* uno    <- 1er commit (a66c2c9)
* dos    <- 1er commit (a66c2c9)

* tres   <- 2do commit (00654ea)
* cuatro <- 2do commit (00654ea)

* cinco  <- 3er commit (3005716)
* seis   <- 3er commit (3005716)
```

Sabiendo que estamos en el commit a66c2c9, digamos que queremos regresarnos al anterior y olvidar todo lo posterior:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Ahora nuestra grafica es:

```
* 00654ea (HEAD -> master) add: archivos tres y cuatro
* 3005716 add:archivos uno y dos
```

Es decir, nos volamos los archivos "cinco" y "seis", y el commit donde fue introducido.

Para recuperar ese commit, podemos utilizar el commando `git reflog` que me parece que nos muestra los registros de las referencias proveidas en la línea de comandos:

```sh
$ git reflog
* a66c2c9 (HEAD -> master) add:archivos cinco y seis
* 00654ea add:archivos tres y cuatro
* 3005716 add:archivos uno y dos
```

Y aquí tenemos el commit al que le habíamos afectado con nuestro reset: a66c2c9

Ahora tan sólo aplicamos de nuevo un reset a ese commit:

```
$ git reset --hard a66c2c9
```

Y nuestra gráfica queda arreglada:

```
* a66c2c9 (HEAD -> master) add:archivos cinco y seis
* 00654ea add:archivos tres y cuatro
* 3005716 add:archivos uno y dos
```

Y nuestros archivos volvieron a su lugar original.